# Pass and receive object pk to fix foreign key field in CreateView in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to build a django app to mantain a class called "Actuacion". Depending on the values of the field "tipo" additional info is required, so I have created a main class "Actuacion" with the common fields, and a different class for each "tipo" with specific fields for each type linked with the main class "Actuacion" through a foreign key.

The model is something like this:

```
models.py

class TipoActuacion(models.Model):
    # Values for "tipo" by the moment are "DEPURACION", "CONSERVACION", "PLANEAMIENTO"
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50)   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tipo

class Actuacion(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey('TipoActuacion', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    # Other common fields


class ActuacionPlaneamiento(models.Model):
    actuacion = models.ForeignKey('Actuacion', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Other fields

class ActuacionDepuracion(models.Model):
    actuacion = models.ForeignKey('Actuacion', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    habitantes = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Other fields

class ActuacionConservacion(models.Model):
    actuacion = models.ForeignKey('Actuacion', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    fecha = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Other fields
```

So, I pretend to create "Actuacion" objects through django class-based views and after creating the main object, depending on the value registered on "tipo" field redirect to the corresponding create view to complete the info.

The main class "Actuacion" is created but I haven't found the way to link it with the child entity (based on field "tipo", for example ActuacionConservacion). I pass the pk of the created Actuacion object in kwargs, but I need to receive this parameter and use it to fix the foreign key field of the child ActuacionConservacion object.

I'm pretty stuck here, any advice is wellcome

```
views.py

class ActuacionCreate(CreateView):
    model = Actuacion
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'pgi/actuacion_create.html'
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        servicio = self.object.tipo
        if servicio.__str__() == 'DEPURACION':
            return reverse('actuacion-depuracion-create', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
        elif servicio.__str__() == 'CONSERVACION':
            return reverse('actuacion-conservacion-create', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
        elif servicio.__str__() == 'PLANEAMIENTO':
            return reverse('actuacion-planeamiento-create', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
        else:
            return reverse('actuacion-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})


class ActuacionConservacionCreate(CreateView):
    model = ActuacionConservacion
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'pgi/actuacion_tipo_create.html'
```

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^actuaciones/$', views.actuacion_list, name='actuacion-list'),
    url(r'^actuacion/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ActuacionDetailView.as_view(), name='actuacion-detail'),
    url(r'^actuacion/create/$'/, views.ActuacionCreate.as_view(), name='actuacion-create'),
    url(r'^actuacion/create/(?P<pk>\d+)/depuracion/$', views.ActuacionDepuracionCreate.as_view(), name='actuacion-depuracion-create'),
    url(r'^actuacion/create/(?P<pk>\d+)/conservacion/$', views.ActuacionConservacionCreate.as_view(), name='actuacion-conservacion-create'),
    url(r'^actuacion/create/(?P<pk>\d+)/planeamiento/$', views.ActuacionPlaneamientoCreate.as_view(), name='actuacion-planeamiento-create'),
    url(r'^actuacion/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', views.ActuacionUpdate.as_view(), name='actuacion-update'),
    url(r'^actuacion/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', views.ActuacionDelete.as_view(), name='actuacion-delete'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there are better ways to achive this, but I manage to link the create forms and fix the foreign key value overwriting the form_valid method on the child entity

```
class ActuacionConservacionCreate(CreateView):
    model = ActuacionConservacion
    fields = ['otracosa']
    template_name = 'pgi/actuacion_tipo_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.actuacion = Actuacion.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(ActuacionConservacionCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```